# Nondeterministic Finite Automata construction

Tags: finite-automata, non-deterministic

It feels like this should be easier than it is, but I am having an issue with it. Here is what is asked:

Construct a NFA for the following language L = {ab,ba}*. So, I understand that I can have any combination of ab or ba in the string, but do I need a dead state if say I get two a's in a row, or does it just start over? Here are the two graphs that I have:
[image: g1]
[image: g2]

Are either of these correct? And since they are NFAs vs DFA do I need a lambda edge somewhere on here?

Edit:
Would this third one be correct because I need two final states?
[image: g3]

Comment: All of your examples are DFAs (and so are NFAs trivially). Your first example is not correct, because it accepts strings outside the language (such as `aab`). Your second and third examples are almost correct but not minimal. Neither DFA accepts the empty string, which is in the language. A minimal DFA with 3 states (or 4 with an explicit dead state) is possible. States `{q1, q2, q3}`, `q1` being the starting and accepting state. Transitions: `q1,a,q2, q1,b,q3, q2,b,q1, q3,a,q1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making an NFA, you don't need dead states; you can just let the NFA crash. DFAs probably do need dead states for completeness, depending on your definitions.

Here is an NFA (`q0` is the initial state and the only accepting state):

```
         b
      +------+
      |      |
      V  a   |    
  +->q0 ---> q1
  |   |
a |   | b
  |   V
  +--q2
```

To make this a DFA you can add a dead state `q3` and make all transitions not otherwise defined above terminate in `q3`.